Can ERDAS Imagine import Excel and AutoCAD files
I am a newbie with ERDAS Imagine and would like to ask about the import/export of this software. Can ERDAS Imagine import Excel and AutoCAD files? If so, is there any documentation to support this? Thanks a lot.

what is "ERDAS Imagine"? is this a programming question? where's the code/[mre]? or is this a program usage question?
